# Improving Linq statement selecting Json

Tags: json, linq, json.net

I have some json like this:

```
[{
    "id": "20148324",
    "teacher", "Mr Jones",
    "names": ["john", "bill", "ben"],
    "priority": 2
},
{ 
    "id": "56128324",
    "teacher", "Mrs Jones"
    "names": ["john", "bill", "ben"],
    "priority": 1
}]
```

I want to be able to first select the child which has a priority value of 1, then in that child i want to select the last name in the nested names array.

I can accomplish this in two steps but was wondering how i can do it with one linq statement.

This is what i have got so far but i only get one dictionary item added. How can i add all the names individually with the teacher name to the dictionary:

```
var things = response.Where(p => p["priority"].Value<int>() == 1)
                             .ToDictionary(m => m["teacher"].ToString(),
                                           m => m["names"].Children().ToString());
```

Comment: I think the last ToString() is not needed. It seems you convert Children() array to string (i.e. "String[]").

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov then it will still return one dictionary item but as dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>(). I need to somehow iterate over the names and also jump back up to the parent to select the teacher name.

Comment: I think I see the problem. You want to get all students of a teacher? Then you need to perform grouping. Something like `response.Where(p => p["priority"].Value<int>() == 1).Group(m => m["teacher"].ToString(), m => m["names"].Children())

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov hi im getting the same thing as before result as before a string and list<string>.

Comment: Can you tell me more exactly what do you want to achieve? Write a sample data with 4-5 items, and show what result data you would like to see. (update the question with these)

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov Hi i eventually have managed to do it, i will post an answer, but if you have a better way please advise. thanks for your input so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually did it with this. Not convinced its the nicest way, but it works.

```
var data = response.Where(p => p["priority"].Value<int>() == 1)
                             .SelectMany(s=>s["names"])
                             .ToDictionary(m => m.Value<string>(),
                                           m => m.Parent.Parent.Parent["teacher"].ToString());
```